# php mvc pass dynamic number of variables to class/function

Tags: php, arrays, dynamic

Did my research on this, couldn't find what I was looking for.  Tried ReflectionClass but that didn't work for me.

I have a class with functions.  The number of variables going into the function is dynamic.

Example:

Included class:

```
class Home {
  function test($var1, $var2, $var3){
    // do stuff here
  }
}

// this class is included based on url params, i.e. example.com/home/test/1/2/3
// where home is class, test is function and 1 2 3 are variables

$variables = array('1','2','3'); // static for this example, but array can have any number of elements to it.

$foo = new Home();
$foo->test($variables);

call_user_func_array('test', $variables);
```

So what I am trying to achieve, is to take the array of variables and send them to the function test as so in the code example, where I can list each one.

This example below does what I would like to do, but how would I apply it to a class/mvc framework?

```
$colors = array('test','maroon','blue','green');
call_user_func_array('setLineColor', $colors);

function setLinecolor($var1, $var2, $var3, $var4){
  echo $var1;
  echo $var2;
}
```

Any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [proper callback](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php) for the object:

```
$foo = new Home();
call_user_func_array( array( $foo, 'test'), $variables);
```

This will invoke the `test()` function on the `$foo` object.

Comment: Ha, perfect!  Didn't even see what I was doing wrong..that's what you get for working on this stuff for hours on end..thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered sending associative array, and then using [extract](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php) with in the function?

Like:

```
// using 
$variables = array('var1'=>'1', 'var2'=>'2', 'var3'=>'3');
// instead of
$variables = array('1','2','3');
```

And, function:

```
function test($variables)
{
extract($variables);
echo $var1;
echo $var2;
}
```

Comment: I experimented with extract and didn't really like it.